# How to send data from background script to popup script?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension, google-chrome-storage

I'm well aware that there are older questions regarding this issue, but I havent't found a solution from them.

My extension is supposed to detect a copy event in contentScript.js and pass the information, that event has been detected to oncopy.js. After that oncopy.js is supposed to copy users clipboard contents and pass them to popup.js, where the content is stored using Googles storage API, and set to the input fields value in popup.html.

The copy detection works perfectly, but I don't know what to do after that. This is my first extension, so I'm still trying to get hang of things.

Here are my manifest.jsons relevant parts:

```
"permissions": [
  "activeTab",
  "storage",
  "clipboardRead"
],

"background": {
  "scripts": ["oncopy.js"],
  "persistent": false
},

"content_scripts": [
  {
    "matches": ["http://*/*", "https://*/*"],
    "js": ["contentScript.js"]
  }
]
```

contentScript.js:

```
// Fires when copy event is detected
document.addEventListener("copy", () => {
    chrome.runtime.sendMessage({event: "copy"}, msg => console.log(msg))
})
```

oncopy.js e.g. the background script:

```
console.log("oncopy.js background scipt is running...");

// When copy event is detected and message of it is received, this starts to run
chrome.runtime.onMessage.addListener((request, sender, sendResponse) => {
    chrome.runtime.sendMessage({ event: "new clipboard" }, () => {
        // This is supposed to get the clipboard contents from user
        bg = chrome.extension.getBackgroundPage();
        bg.document.body.innerHTML = "";

        var helperdiv = bg.document.createElement("div");
        document.body.appendChild(helperdiv);
        helperdiv.contentEditable = true;

        var range = document.createRange();
        range.selectNode(helperdiv);
        window.getSelection().removeAllRanges();
        window.getSelection().addRange(range);
        helperdiv.focus();

        bg.document.execCommand("Paste");

        var clipboardContents = helperdiv.innerHTML;
    });

    sendResponse("Message has been processed by background page");
});
```

popup.js:

```
// This is supposed to set all of the clipboards to input fields values
document.body.onload = () => {
    chrome.storage.sync.get("clipboards", (clipboards) => {
        if (!chrome.runtime.error) {
            document.getElementById("clipboard1").value = clipboards[0];
        }
    });
};

// The function that gets clipboard contents in oncopy.js is supposed to pass the contents here
// addClipboard is supposed to handle multiple clipboards, but for the sake of simplicity I'm using one as an example
function addClipboard(clipboard) {
    chrome.storage.get("clipboards", (clipboards) => {
        clipboards[0] = clipboard;

        chrome.storage.sync.set({'clipboards': clipboards}, () => {
            message('Clipboard saved');
        });

        document.getElementById("clipboard1").value = clipboards[0];  
    });
```

}

and finally the popup.html:

```
<h2>Clipboards</h2>
    <form>
        <input type="text" id="clipboard1" value="Empty" readonly>
    </form>
```

Comment: Currently your background page receives the message from content script then sends a message to the popup(s). But there's no message listener in your popup, also that second message will be received only while the popup is open. Overall it's not clear why you're using such a scheme. I think you can paste the clipboard and save the data to chrome.storage.local right in the content script and detect this fact in your popup using chrome.storage.onChanged event - no need for the background page.

Comment: @wOxxOm wow, that seems like a really nice way of doing this, thanks!